# Debian Solr Version

Tags: debian, solr

Looking into installing [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) on Debian, I've noticed the Debian packages are all for Solr 3.6.2, which is positively ancient, considering the latest stable version of Solr is 6.3.0.

Is there any reason I should stick to the Debian-packaged version? My instinct is that such an old version should probably be avoided, but installing from official packages has its advantages.

Also, what is the reason for Debian having not updated their Solr packages for so long?

Answer (score 1):

Debian stable focuses on stability over new features. With each release most packages are locked at that version and only get hotfixes to fix security issues.

You can see any security issues posted about a package at https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/

After a cursory search I was able to determine that the package available in the Debian repository is the latest version of the 3.x series and could not find any security advisories about it.

If you care about having the latest version & features of Solr then I'd recommend installing it from the official website. Keep in mind you might have issues with out of date dependencies that cause the newest version to not function or have problems.

Comment: 1. It's the same on all Debian flavors - Stable, Testing, Experimental etc. 
2. Even Debian Stable was released April 2015 - at the time Solr 4.10 was available for a few months already.

Comment: Yeah there's very little information out there about Debian's solr packages. If I was deploying it I would definitely use the latest version and deal with manual updates & dependency issues.